# ensure data integrity with computed column

Tags: database-design, database-schema

I wonder if calculated columns can break data integrity, and views are the solution, if it is correct then why ?

Comment: Define "calculated column".  Do you mean a computed column in those databases that support declarative computations in tables?  Or do you mean a regular column into which your application stores a calculation that you perform in code?

Answer (score 0):

Calculated columns *can* break data integrity. If you build a table like this

```
create table line_items (
  order_num integer primary key references orders (order_num),
  line_item_num integer not null,
  qty integer not null,
  price_each decimal (13, 2) not null,
  price_extended decimal (13, 2) not null
);
```

the dbms doesn't guarantee that the extended price is always the product of "qty" and "price_each". You *can* guarantee that, though, with a CHECK constraint.

```
price_extended decimal (13, 2) not null
    check (price_extended = qty * price_each)
```

In production, you'd *also* have CHECK constraints on "line_item_num", "qty", and "price_each". Probably none of those should be negative, and there should be a reasonable upper bound on each of them, too.

You can build that table without the column "price_extended", and instead calculate it in a view.

```
create view line_items_extended as 
    select order_num, line_item_num, qty, price_each,
           qty * price_each as price_extended
```

The tradeoff is in performance. The view guarantees the right values for "price_extended" without requiring a CHECK constraint on "price_extended". But it has to calculate all or part of "price_extended" values every time the view is used.

Using a view also increases complexity somewhat. Instead of running SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements against a single table, you *probably* need to either

- run SELECT statements against the view, and run all the other statements against the base table, or
- create an updatable view, which requires writing, testing, and maintaining procedural code (commonly triggers).

Comment: In most databases single table views are updateable without the need for procedural code.  Computed columns in the view are not updateable, of course, but the other columns are.

Comment: @LarryLustig:While that's true, in my example--which might have *nothing* at all to do with the OP's real problem--the view would probably need to include a join on a table of orders. Fewer SQL platforms support updating views that include a join.

Comment: Your example shows a situation in which the computed column is derived in a single-table view, which can then be joined with other relations if necessary.  I routinely use views like this (and a very similar naming convention, appending Ex (for extended) to the table name -- admittedly not so great in table names like CustomersEx).